# GRIB files with incremental updates

Tags: grib

Folks,

I am new to dealing with GRIB format and seek your advice on the following question:

we have an application where we plan to receive data at every 6 hour interval. The forecast will be for next 10 to 15 days.

There is a requirement where to reduce the download size, the system should only download incremental changes meaning the new GRIB files will only contain data which has changed.

So all the previously downloaded GRIB files should display data and for the parts where there was a change (assuming clients will know) the client will downloaded and display the GRIB file which has this incremental update ..

Is this kind of incremental changes to GRIB supported by standard?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this option is not supported by GRIB files. As the data in GRIB files is packed, you cannot know what variables have changed and which not.

In addition, most likely most of the parameters have a slight and insignificant change between the forecasts (I mean the forecast for let us say 07:00 o'clock done at 00:00 and done at 06:00 will have differences for most of the parameters, but they can be in order of 10^-X - meaning they are insignificant). Some parameters or regions of course might have larger differences that you would like to highlight.